# Gradle dependency autocompletion in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, autocomplete, dependencies

I've been searching around for a while and can't seem to find anything regarding this issue. I'm new to Java in general and for the last half a year I've been learning Maven. I use IntelliJ IDEA and I'm already used to the fact that it can autocomplete dependency coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version) if you sync the repository. It works nicely and it feels natural when you decide to add some dependency after the initial project generation.

Now I'm trying to switch to Gradle (which is a requirement on my new job) and I'm studying it. And I can't get over the first roadblock that I've encountered with it: there is no autocompletion and it even seems like IntelliJ IDEA's support for this kind of feature has degraded over time (I saw a video of old version of IDEA where there used to be a "Generate" -> "Add maven dependency" option, which I cannot find in the latest version). I even tried a bunch of plugins with names like "Gradle Dependency Helper" and non of them worked.

Are we supposed to type the whole dependency coordinates to add them to gradle build? Because that feels like a big downside of Gradle with IDEA. Or is there some well hidden feature that I missed?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html?

Comment: Yes, nothing relevant there.

Answer (score 0):

You may manage Gradle dependencies in Intellij IDEA using <kbd>View</kbd>→<kbd>Tool windows</kbd>→<kbd>Dependencies</kbd>.

It allows to add or remove dependencies from `dependencies` section in your `build.gradle` and gives full-text search for available dependencies.

[image: Dependencies management window screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for asking here. My IDEA seems cannot figure are what packages have been installed. Even if I create a new project with the official wizard, the dependencies panel keeps saying "No supported dependencies were found in any module". When I search something, e.g. mysql connector, there is always an info sign in the left of add, showing "Maven Central repository will be added.". Clicking add button will produce the message "producing build files" but won't modify my build.gradle in fact. I've wasted several hours on that, I'll be fairly grateful if any possible solution is provided.